# Changing keyboard settings for Mac on Centos7

Tags: keyboard

I have troubles with my keyboard on my centos (VM) because I'm working with a Mac (host). I'm from Belgium so I'm using 'azerty'.

I followed the Red Hat documentation but it did not work:

```
[l@localhost ~]$ localectl list-keymaps | grep be
be
be-iso-alternate
be-latin1
be-nodeadkeys
be-oss
be-oss_latin9
be-oss_sundeadkeys
be-sundeadkeys
be-wang
fr-bepo
fr-bepo_latin9
mac-be
wangbe
wangbe2
```

So there is a mac-be available for my country so I'm doing the following:

```
[l@localhost ~]$ localectl set-keymap mac-be
[l@localhost ~]$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: mac-be
      X11 Layout: be-iso-alternate
```

Even after rebooting it's still not working. I'm not albe to use the copy-paste keys and to use symbols like '\' and '|'.
I also tried to change be-iso-alternate to be-latin1 but this also did not help.

I'm using VMware Fusion. Don't know if this is important.

Comment: I have the same issue with `mac-fr`. You can use the right-hand keys (instead of the left-hand). Don't know why, but it's work for `~`, `|` and `\\`.